# PHP Quiz (getting user answers and comparing arrays)

Tags: php, arrays

I am a bit new to php and I need to create a **quiz website**. I have been searching a lot but I couldn't find the exact code that I need.

On the first page, the user will see questions, answers and he can choose answers by clicking radio buttons. Once submitted, I want to compare on the next page 2 arrays of answers (user answers and the correct answers).

The correct answers array may look like this:
$res1 = array(b,a,b,c,b,d,a,b,c,b);
I believe I should use "for" or "for each" but I don't know how to write it.

The next step will be incrementing the quiz score in case the compared values are equal (user choice: b and correct answer: b)

Comment: We won't write the code for you.  You might want to start with a PHP tutorial to learn the basics first (`for`, `while`, `if`).  If you have this basic understanding and *concrete* questions, come back and ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution for you:

First, create a form like this:

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="question_1" value="a" />
<input type="radio" name="question_1" value="b" />
<input type="radio" name="question_1" value="c" />

<input type="radio" name="question_2" value="a" />
<input type="radio" name="question_2" value="b" />
<input type="radio" name="question_2" value="c" />
...
</form>
```

In php, do something like this:

```
$answers = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', ...);
$points  = 0;

for($i=0; $i < count($answers); $i++) {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['question_'.($i+1)]) && $_REQUEST['question_'.($i+1)] == $answers[$i]) 
        $points++;
}

echo $points;
```

Comment: Good sample but I recommend syncing array and and question numbers. Otherwise you may end up with problems. $answers = array(1=> 'a', ....) would do.

Comment: Sascha, if you start with question_0 then your display will be out of sync with the human readable numbers, unless of course, your site is related with programming and you start with question 0 :)

Comment: Thank you!
This worked for me:

$answers = array(0=> 'A', 1=> 'B', 2=> 'C');

for($i=0; $i < count($answers); $i++) {
 if (isset($_REQUEST['a'.($i+1)]) && $_REQUEST['a'.($i+1)] == $answers[$i]) 
  $score++;
 }

(I replaced question_ with a)